# Using parts of android lib in non-android project

Tags: java, android, desktop

I am currently attempting to port an android app to desktop. I realize that the majority of the android based code cannot be reused, but what about "smaller parts" which dont depend on the android architecture?

I am mostly talking about support or math related classes like SparseArray, Matrix and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Those may work. But you will have a rough time figuring out what works and what doesn't. Even once you do that you will need to create a whitelist somewhere like in your IDE that doesn't auto-complete classes you don't want or can't use and you will also want to fail your build. Maybe you should create a jar containing only the classes you want to use that you determine are usable.